# center h1 vertically and horizontally in an img element

Tags: html, css

How do you center `h1` in an `img` element, when the image is 100% of screens width and always maintaining aspect ratio? [This  pen shows what I mean](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbryXX). I've seen some answers here on SO, but the image always had width and height fixed.

Comment: img-element does not allow any content https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img Maybe you just need a background-image with css?

Comment: try setting position relative to wrapper div and absolute to h1.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to achieve your goal you need to put both img and h1 into a div and use positioning to center the h1

```css
#headerImage {
    width:100%;        
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
   }

#greeting{
  
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;

}

#greetin-h1{
text-align: center;
color:#000;
  position: absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  
}
```

```html
<div id="greeting">
    <img id="headerImage" src="http://study.com/cimages/course-image/intro-to-business-syllabus-resource-lesson-plans_138757_large.jpg" alt=""/>
    <h1 id="greetin-h1">THIS IS H1 ELEMENT</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: man! you saved me! 3 hours trying different solutions with no luck!

Comment: Glad that helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Why not using the image as background?

```css
html, body{
  width: 100vw;
}
#greeting{
padding: 140px 20px 50px 20px;
background-image: url("http://study.com/cimages/course-image/intro-to-business-syllabus-resource-lesson-plans_138757_large.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

#greetin-h1{
  text-align: center;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
 <div id="greeting">
  <h1 id="greetin-h1">THIS IS H1 ELEMENT</h1>
 </div>
```

Comment: To address the question why not using a background-image? I really wanted to stuff alt attribute in it.

Comment: Like what kind of attributes? We might be able to make them work anyways

Comment: alt attribute. Some say it alt tag. It isnt defined for background-image, since background images are decorative.

Comment: Also, having img tag is useful for resposiveness, you can adapt image to 100% width for example, and height auto, and block will adjust to image size in every resolution

Answer (score 1):

## greeting add css style

```
#greetin {
            padding: 140px 20px 50px 20px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://www.propointgraphics.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/stock-photos-vince_3219813k.jpg" alt="">
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the image isn't full screen width.

Comment: background-size: cover makes it be as big as the container, so if the container covers the whole screen width, the image will too.

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of relative and absolute positioning, table and table-cell display like this:

**CSS:**

```
#headerImage {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
#headerImage img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
#greeting {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#greetin-h1 {
    margin: 0;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#greetin-h1 span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="headerImage">
   <div id="greeting">
      <h1 id="greetin-h1"><span>THIS IS H1 ELEMENT</span></h1>
   </div>
   <img src="http://study.com/cimages/course-image/intro-to-business-syllabus-resource-lesson-plans_138757_large.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ve8sot21/1

This way the h1 will always be centered horizontally and vertically no matter the image dimension.